# spark - detail explanation on data_format function

Tags: apache-spark, datetime

Where is `date_format` explained in detail such as what format is accepted in `timestamp` or `expr` argument?

- [Spark documentation - date_format](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#date_format)

> date_format(timestamp, fmt) - Converts timestamp to a value of string in the format specified by the date format fmt.
>
> - timestamp - A date/timestamp or string to be converted to the given format.
> - fmt - Date/time format pattern to follow. See Datetime Patterns for valid date and time format patterns.

- [Databricks documentation - date_format](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/date_format.html)

> date_format(expr, fmt)
>
> - expr: A DATE, TIMESTAMP, or a STRING in a valid datetime format.
> - fmt: A STRING expression describing the desired format.

`2007-11-13` is OK for the timestamp expression but `2007-NOV-13` is not. Where is the explanation of this behavior?

```
spark.sql("select date_format(date '2007-11-13', 'MMM') AS month_text").show()
+----------+
|month_text|
+----------+
|       Nov|
+----------+
```

```
spark.sql("select date_format(date '2007-JAN-13', 'MMM') AS month_text").show()
...
ParseException: 
Cannot parse the DATE value: 2007-JAN-13(line 1, pos 19)
```

I suppose the time expression needs to be ISO 8601 but it should be documented somewhere.

Timestamp expression can be `date '2007-11-13'` or `timestamp '2007-11-13'` but where can I get the information of this expression format?

Answer (score 1):

`date '...'` is a [datetime literal](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-literals.html#datetime-literal) and it has to follow a specific pattern. It's mostly used when you need to hardcode a date or you already have a datetime in ISO-8601 format.

To parse a date from string you use [to_date](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#to_date) function. To convert string representation from one format to the other first you parse with `to_date`, then format with `date_format`. In your case:

```
scala> spark.sql("select date_format(to_date('2007-JAN-13', 'yyyy-MMM-dd'), 'MMM') AS month_text").show()
+----------+
|month_text|
+----------+
|       Jan|
+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the datetime literal link. Did not know it.